# How do you show the path of the current running python module?

Tags: python, path

How do you show the path of the current running python module?
Which would print `/Users/user/documents/python/bla.py` if bla.py was placed in `/Users/user/documents/python/`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want a module to know where it's at even when imported, you should be able to use

```
import sys

sys.modules[__name__].__file__
```

I know this includes the absolute path on my linux system but I've heard it said that it doesn't on Windows.

Comment: It doesn't include absolute path even on linux system. Tested against Debian linux 6

Comment: @Tyler weird. I was running ubuntu 10.04 at the time I posted this answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 8):

```
import os
print os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for files in the same directory as the file that was invoked to start execution of the program.

Comment: @aaron you are right, I think it should fit what OP is asking for