# Doing smart things with __file__ in python (what are they talking about?)

Tags: python, python-module

I keep seeing reference saying something like:

> "people doing smart thing with `__file__`"

mostly in the context of the python packaging [and packaging wars](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2012/6/22/hate-hate-hate-everywhere/).

Guess I'm missing something because as far as I can tell this is just an attribute of the model specifing the file name and path, as explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-wildcard-mean-do)

what's so special about `__file__` and what are some examples for "clever things" people are doing with it?

Comment: Well, there's an example in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/python-3-relative-imports/16985066#16985066) I wrote, but this question is a bit too vague to give a particularly meaningful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to load the code you're working via `import` by putting its project directory under your PYTHONPATH, and the code depends on data files you've stored in the project directory, you can use `__file__` to get the project location and retrieve the data.

I like to load everything I work on via `import`, but my coworkers run the scripts I give them inside their project directories from the command line. So in these scripts I use a `getwd` function defined as follows to get the correct location of the project files, regardless of how the script is run:

```
import os
def getwd():
    return os.path.dirname(__file__) if '__file__' in globals() else os.getcwd()
```

When I load the script via `import`, `getwd` returns the directory of the script. When my coworkers run the script from the command line inside their project directory, there is no global `__file__`, and `getwd` simply returns the current directory.