# Issue with Exception in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I have a chunk of Python code that is supposed to create MySQL schemas when executed. The issue is that whenever I run it, I get an error saying `Raise Exception(e). Exception: [Error 2] the system cannot find the file specified`

Below is my code:

```
from test.db.db import DB
from test.config import loggingSetup
loggingSetup.initializeLogging("createTest.py")
import logging

def createSports(db):
   sqlFile = "..\\sql\\createSchema.sql"

   db.run(sqlFile)

def create():
   db=DB()

   createSports(db)

def Main():
    create()

if__name__=='__main__':
   try:
      main()
   except Exception, e:
      logging.info(e.message)
      raise Exception(e)
```

Now I will admit, this code isn't entirely mine. I found this online, and I'm trying to rework it so it will fit my needs. My experience with python is minimal at best, but you have to start somewhere. On a basic level I under stand that the if statement is saying `if __name__=='__main__' then try main()`, but i guess I'm fuzzy as to why this exception is being thrown. I know this chunk of code has worked for others who have used it for similar projects, is there something wrong with my syntax that is throwing this off?

Comment: Did you check the file `sql/createSchema.sql` exist?

Comment: Try to provide the full path to `createSchema.sql`

Comment: @falsetru the file does exist and I've changed the code to provide the full path. unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
initialize_logging(__file__)
```

It's because the file which you pass to the logging function isn't found. **file** in short gives you the path to the currently loaded module.

Read more about **file** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-wildcard-mean-do).

Comment: Ryan, correct, but I think that the guy just wants it to work and not to start REing paths in Python, you know? By the way windows paths are case insensitive

Comment: Awesome! I'll add an explanation soon

Comment: @Jcmoney1010 was the explanation good? Or do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

```
def createSports(db):
   sqlFile = "..\\sql\\createSchema.sql" #file path goes here
```

in here you have to write your file path. It's an example. Complete the path and make sure this file is exist.

Comment: I added the full path to the createSchema.sql file. This changed the above line to `sqlFile = "C:\User\Desktop\Test\sql\createSchema.sql"` but unfortunately I'm getting the same error as before.

Comment: You didn't double up the backslashes (or use a raw string).

Answer (score 0):

You should know the difference between "working directory" and actually directory. During the runtime, if you don't use the absolute path, the Code(not only python, but other language such as C++, Java), will treat the path as relative path. so the question is what it is relative to ? the answer is "working directory", you can change your working directory easily by "`os.chdir`". In this case, you need to transfer it to the absolute path:

```
solution:
```

1)

```
def createSports(db):
    sqlFile = "..\\sql\\createSchema.sql"
    sqlFile = os.path.abspath(sqlFile)
    if not os.path.exists(sqlFile):
        msg = "file %s doesn't exist" % sqlFile
        raise Exception(msg)
    else:
       db.run(sqlFile)
```

2） use the full path, but pay attention to the escaped character, you should use this `sqlFile = r"C:\User\Desktop\Test\sql\createSchema.sql"`, use the "r" to mean that this is raw sting, do NOT escape "\"

Comment: hmm, solution one gives me an `unexpected indent` error on all the new lines added. Solution 2 gives me the same error I started with. This is driving me crazy! thanks for your help though!

Comment: r"C:\User\Desktop\Test\sql\createSchema.sql"  if this doesn't work, then you should check if you have enough privileges to that file.