# Accepted practice to provide access to a module-relative file in a setup.py application

Tags: python, setup.py

(Sorry for the wall of text, but I wanted to make sure all relevant details of my problem are included)

I am roughly following the application structure outlined [here](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject). I also have a `logging.conf` file, which I want my application to use in all cases:

- when calling my application with `python -m myapp` (I have a `__main__.py` for that)
- when doing `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3`, ... (I have some `console_scripts` in `setup.py:entry_points`)

The structure is roughly:

```
myapp/
├── build
├── dist
├── MANIFEST.in
├── myapp
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── helpers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── startup.py
│   ├── logging.conf
│   ├── cmd
│   │   ├── cmd1.py
│   │   ├── cmd2.py
│   │   ├── cmd3.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── tox.ini
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests
└── venv
```

In one of my modules (`lib/startup.py`), used in all of my application entry points (`__main__.py`, `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3`, ...) I am (early) loading the logger configuration, with

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

In my `MANIFEST.in`, the `logging.conf` is installed. Everything seems to be installed correctly in the virtualenv when doing `python setup.py install`:

- the application is properly installed
- the `logging.conf` is copied
- the scripts (`cmd1`, ...) are created

And the application can be started, in all provided ways:

- `python -m myapp`
- `cmd1`, `cmd2`, `cmd3`

And I can also run it in my dev environment:

```
myapp/myapp $ python cmd/cmd1.py
```

But, whereas in the development environment `logging.conf` is found without problems (it is in the `cwd`), the installed module can not locate this file, and execution fails:

```
$ python -m cmd1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "myapp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/myapp-0.5.0-py3.4.egg/myapp/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from myapp.cmd.cmd1 import main
  File "myapp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/myapp-0.5.0-py3.4.egg/myapp/cmd/cmd1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myapp.lib.startup import start_trading
  File "myapp/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/myapp-0.5.0-py3.4.egg/myapp/lib/startup.py", line 10, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 937, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

How can I ensure that my installed application is able to find a module-relative file? I can not use absolute paths in my code, because I do not know the installation path ... Are there any recommended best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER.** I'm not sure whether this approach is accepted practice. But it's definitely the simplest one.

You can use [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/1377864) global variable to get relative path to the currently running *.py file. Having it you can calculate path to the *resource* file. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918178/1377864) for more details.

Given your example, you can calculate path to the `logging.conf` inside `startup.py` like this:

```
import os

# path to the logging.conf
config_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../logging.conf')
print(config_path)

# normalized path to the logging.conf (optionally) 
norm_config_path = os.path.normpath(config_path)
print(norm_config_path)
```