# importing a python function from a file in other directory which depends on another file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

This is my directory structure

```
-directory1
  |-currentlyWritingCode
-directory2
  |-__init__.py
  |-helper.py
  |-view.ui
```

The helper.py is a UI from pyqt4 framework. It needs the view.ui file . 
it has following code to load the ui data

```
viewBase, viewForm = uic.loadUiType("view.ui")
```

now in directory1 in the currently writing code I did this

```
import directory2.helper
```

when I run the code in currentlyWritingCode it is throwing an error that

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'view.ui'
```

What to do now?

using python3.5 from anaconda on Centos 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),'view.ui')` in place of `view.ui`. This will ensure you correctly reference the folder that the python file lives in, regardless of the code that imports it.

Note: Make sure you have `import os` with your other imports.

### How does this work?

`__file__` is an attribute of the module you are importing. It contains the path to the module file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271617/1994235). However, this path is not necessarily an absolute path. `os.path.realpath` returns the absolute path (it even follows [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) if there are any). At this point we have a full path to the module, so we take the path to the directory (`os.path.dirname`) and join it with the original filename (which we assumed to be relative to the original module and so should be in the aforementioned directory). `os.path.join` ensures that the correct `\` or `/` is used when constructing a file path so that the code works on any platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. Can you explain me how it is working. I think it is somehow giving the absolute path to the file dynamically. And what is that  _ __file__ _  parameter? I never saw that kind of parameter. Kind of enum?

Comment: Hi @srinath29 I've updated my answer with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @three_pineapples . . I understood.