# How to get full path to python program including filename within the program?

Tags: python, path, python-os

I have a python program, and I want to get the path to the program from within the program, but INCLUDING the file name itself. The name of my file is PyWrapper.py. Right now I'm doing this:

```
import sys,os
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
fullpath = os.path.abspath(pathname)
print fullpath
```

The output is:

```
 /home/mrpickles/Desktop/HANSTUFF/securesdk/src/
```

This is the path to the directory in which my file is saved, but I would like it to output:

```
/home/mrpickles/Desktop/HANSTUFF/securesk/src/PyWrapper.py/
```

Which is the path, including the filename itself. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `__file__`. This gives you a filename where the code actually **is**.

Also, there's another option:

```
import __main__ as main
print(main.__file__)
```

This gives you a filename of a script being **run** (similar to what your `argv` does).

The difference comes into play when the code is imported by another script.

Answer (score 0):

```
print __file__
```

should work.

`__file__` returns the path of the executed file

Comment: So what I'm trying to do is get the full pathname including the filename and pass it into another function as an argument. Could I set some variable as equal to __file__? Eg, fullpath = __file__?

Comment: Also for some reason the formatting god rid of the two underscores before and after file in the previous comment

Comment: the formatting problem is because two underscores usually stand for bold, unless you put them in a code wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you would like to find the absolute path for other files, not just the one you are currently running, in that same directory, a general approach could look like this:

```
import sys,os

pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
fullpath = os.path.abspath(pathname)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fullpath):
    for name in files:
        name = str(name)
        name = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root,name))
        print name
```

As others are mentioning, you could take advantage of the `__file__` attribute. You can use the `__file__` attribute to return several different paths relevant to the currently loaded Python module (copied from [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/5209610)):

> When a module is loaded in Python, **file** is set to its name. You can then use that with other functions to find the directory that the file is located in.

```
# The parent directory of the directory where program resides.
print os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')

# The canonicalised (?) directory where the program resides.
print os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# The absolute path of the directory where the program resides.
print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Remember to be wary of where the module you are loading came from. It could affect the contents of the `__file__` attribute (copied from [Python 3 Data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)):

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file. The `__file__` attribute **may be missing for certain types of modules**, such as C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter; for extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library, it is the pathname of the shared library file.

Answer (score 0):

try using `__file__`. as long as the module is ran from a file, i.e. not code in an editor, `__file__` will be the abs path to the module!

```
print __file__
```

Or for command line.

```
def get_my_name():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.curdir, __file__))
    else:
        return __file__.replace('.pyc', '.py')
```

Comment: No it isn't.  If I run my script like this: `python foo.py`, `__file__` will just be __foo.py__.

Comment: You are correct, didn't know the OP was considering running the program in such a primitive way... Updated origonal