# sys.argv[0] is not showing the name of file in python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

If I understand correctly, When typing sys.argv[0] it shows the name of the .py file one is working on. But when I  do this, it shows me a different name:

```
sys.argv[0]
'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\spyderlib\\widgets\\externalshell\\start_ipython_kernel.py'
```

The real name of the file is *'Ra x 13 arima.py'* and its located in *'C:\Users\infantjo\Documents\Python Scripts\Projects\Work in Progress'*

The current directory  is:

```
os.getcwd()
'C:\\Users\\infantjo\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Projects'
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Im using Python 2.7.11 in Spyder 2.3.8 installed with Anaconda 2.3.0, 64bit).

Comment: What do you mean by *'working on'*? Do you mean running? `sys.argv[0]` gives the name of the script which was run as an entry point to the running process. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

Comment: sorry, yes I mean the code I'm running.

Comment: `getcwd()` is the working directory. That's a completely different thing from the directory your code is in. Why do you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Are you in an interactive prompt? `ipython` is Interactive Python. The script to start the prompt process is the one you quote above. It looks as though you aren't running your script.

Comment: *nod*. If your question is where the current module's source came from, that's a **completely** different question.

Comment: How You run the code?

Comment: I'm running the code in Spyder.

Comment: Looks like `ipython`/`spyder` is wrapping your script.  You could fall back to `__file__`, but it gives you the filename of the current module.  Each py file will give you its name, so you would need to only reference your main module's `__file__`.

Comment: thanks @rrauenza but I didn't understand your comment

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-wildcard-mean-do/9271617

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` contain a list of command line arguments passed to python script. `argv[0]` is the script name. [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

IDE like Spyder / PyCharm doesn't run the script direct. It's run the wrapper that run Your script.

In this case Spyder run the `start_ipython_kernel.py` script that get a Your script name as a parameter and run it.

If You need a script name use a `__file__` var.