# Python) Is there any way to get current directory location where certain file exists in?

Tags: python

I know that `os.get_cwd()` returns current directory. But problem is that it returns directory where you execute `python`, not the certain file exists in.

For example, below is the directory structure:

```
my_test_dir
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── test1
    ├── __init__.py
    └── util.py
```

Let say I insert `print(os.get_cwd())` in `util.py`. And `main.py` import `util`. If I run `main.py` in `my_test_dir`, then it prints `my_test_dir`, not `my_test_dir/test1` because I execute this python program in `my_test_dir`.

What I want to do is to make it print `my_test_dir/test1`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does the \_\_file\_\_ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with Windows os, to avoid any kind of trouble, you can do:

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do/9271617