# How to determine path where the file is located?

Tags: python, filepath

I start my python code file foo.py from directory `home/a/b/`.

The file `foo.py` is located at `home/x/y/k`.

Inside the file `foo.py` what can be the way to get path `home/x/y/k`.

I have used the functions `os.getcwd()` and `os.path.realpath()`, they all return `home/a/b`.

I will appreciate any help in the direction.

Comment: check out \__file__ see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do/9271617

Comment: Your current working directory is the directory from where the file is being executed. You must execute the file from your home directory to get absolute location of your file.

Comment: @InfectedDrake I understand this, however, i do not have the option to execute the file from the home directory.

Comment: do you mean to change the path? you can use os.chdir(path) to change your current working directory inside python code.

Comment: @taipei, no I do not need to change the path. From the code, I require the path from where the file foo.py is located and not from where it is getting executed.

Comment: `from pathlib import Path; script_directory = Path(__file__).parent`

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` inside the foo.py file.
This way, you will always get the path of your foo.py, no matter from where you start the script.

Comment: Yes, I use this on some of my code. You need to pass the `__file__` argument into abspath. `__file__` is always refer to the python file where it is declared. If you only need to get the directory, use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`.

Comment: I'd recommend linking to the relevant docs as well. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. It works for me. I can get the path where the file is located.

Comment: Great! By the way, If you believe my answer is helpful, do not hesitate to make it as accepted answer. Thanks!