# Python Current Folder of Script

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to return the current folder path of a python script, here is what I have

```
#test.py
import os
THIS_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))
print(THIS_FOLDER)
```

When I run this script, it returns the folder that I am in when running it in the command prompt, not the folder of the python script.. How can I return the folder of the current python file?

```
user@vm:~$ python -u dir/test.py
/home/user
```

```
user@vm:~$ cd dir
user@vm:~/dir$ python -u test.py
/home/user/dir
```

Comment: the quotes around `__file__` look bogus

Comment: @user66081 yep, that fixed it. thanks

Comment: @user66081 actually, it works in python on linux, but not in my jupyter notebook in windows.. `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: @Adam12344 `abspath` takes string and assumes it's a relative path, usually with a filename at the end which is unchanged

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes around `__file__`

In your script `os.path.abspath` gets a string `'__file__'` and returns `'/home/user/__file__'` (same as `./__file__` on *nix).

`os.path.dirname` then just strips the filename at the end of the string so your working directory (`./`) is left.

*Edit:* You want the absolute path of the folder that contains the script (`__file__`)
That becomes: `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do/) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work in Jupyter Notebooks? Removing the quotes makes it work when running the file in linux

Comment: @Adam12344 I updated the answer and linked a similar answer for you.