# How to get the path of the file and not the current working directory

Tags: python, directory

So I have a python file sample.py which is in let's say 'A/B/C' and my current working directory is let's say 'D/E'. Now in sample.py I am needed it's directory that is 'A/B/C' . Can anyone help me with this. I have tried `"dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__sample__'))"` but it returns the current working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:
`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__sample__'))`

to

`dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

This should work for you. Find more about `__file__` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do).

Comment: Your answer is assuming that the script is imported. Also you might want to consider flagging the question as a duplicate instead of duplicating an answer.

Comment: @gst well that's what the question interprets. Also, for the flagging part, I've flagged it already. However, it seems that the user has some misunderstanding about the accepted answer of the question you're referring to.