# Python difference between __file__ and os.path.realpath(__file__)

Tags: python

The title sums it up, what is the difference between `__file__` and `os.path.realpath(__file__)`?

```
import os

print((__file__)) #/Users/tom/Documents/Code/Python/LearnPython/playingname.py
print(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #/Users/tom/Documents/Code/Python/LearnPython/playingname.py
print(type(__file__)) #<class 'str'>
print(type(os.path.realpath(__file__))) #<class 'str'>
```

Is `os.path.realpath` redundant?

Comment: If you have symbolic links in the path you'll see a difference.

Comment: Hint: symlinks.

Comment: Worth a [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on Windows.