# How to open file located in same folder as Python script

Tags: python

I have a folder named `study` in which I have a JSON file named `data.json` but when I'm trying to open it in a python script located in the same folder, I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.json'`.

When I use the full, absolute path to `data.json`, however, it works.

How do I fix this such that I can specify the path of `data.json` to be in the same folder as my .py file?

Here is my code:

```
import json

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

def translate(w):
    return data[w]

word = input("Enter word: ")

print(translate(word))
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do). This will enable you to specify paths that are relative to the location of your Python script file.

```
import os

data_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "data.json")
data = json.load(open(data_file_path))
```

Alternatively, using `pathlib` instead of `os`:

```
from pathlib import Path

data_file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "data.json"
data = json.load(open(data_file_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
load_my_file('./file_name.etc')
```

**Explanation:** `./` is the local directory. Possible for local and for testing. You could change it later, but `./` and then the `file_name` is pretty fast to code

It's a regular expression from unix. More info: ["What Does ./ Mean In Linux?"](https://allthings.how/what-does-mean-in-linux/)

Comment: `./` is the default location where Python will try to open the file. I don't see how adding it could help.