# why do I have to add a higher folder when opening a file in python when debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have a directory tree similar to this:

```
my_application
    my_component
        process_config.py
        process_config.yaml
    runner.py
```

I launch `python runner.py` and it calls a class inside `process_config.py` that reads the yaml file like this:

```
with open(
   os.path.join("my_component", "process_config.yaml"), "r"
) as proces_config_defaults_source:
```

And it works fine when y run `python runner.py`, but it can't locate the file when I run the file from the debugger. I have to use this option for it to work:

```
with open(
    os.path.join("my_application", "my_component", "process_config.yaml"), "r"
) as proces_config_defaults_source:
```

How can I make the debugger to work the same as a python run?

Comment: I don't think the debugger is your immediate problem here. If your file exists directly next to `runner.py`, you should use a relative path, anyway, not refer to the parent folders

Comment: @OneCricketeer you're right, mi description of the issue was wrong. Sorry about it

Comment: Could you please attach your `launch.json` to the issue, if you use `"program": "${file}",`, will it be solved?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/61586037/2308683