# How do I open a file in a Python program if the error I'm getting says the file doesn't exist? It exists in my fileexplorer

Tags: python, windows, thonny

How do I open a file in a **Python** program if the error I'm getting says the file doesn't exist? It exists in my fileexplorer.

**Error message**:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.txt'
```

I tried to open a different file, which also didn't work. Do I need to transfer the file to another directory, or try a different line of code?

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname. You're probably using a relative path and your current working directory isn't where you thought it was

Comment: If you open a file like this `open("Test.txt")` then place it in directory where you run the script. Otherwise check your running directory and file location.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586037/how-to-open-file-located-in-same-folder-as-python-script) help at all?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the address of the file as full pathname rather than relative!

```
C:\home\sally\statusReport
```

Above is the example of absolute path