# Building path in python

Tags: python, django

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(
      os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), 'templates')],
```

resolves to:

```
'/opt/python/current/app/src/myproject/templates'
```

What change would I need to make to may code to get DIRS to resolve to the following?

```
'/opt/python/current/app/src/templates'
```

Comment: Can you post the original `__file__` value? ... or its abspath, really.

Comment: I don't pass file into this.

Comment: You used `__file__` and you could print absolute path to use as test input. That would make this a reproducible problem we can use for test. Otherwise we have to invent a path name ourselves and try it.

Comment: See my answer for an example. I guessed instead of verifying because I don't have sample input.

Answer (score 1):

`pathlib` can make this easier. Its like `os.path` but implemented as a class suitable for method chaining.

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = "would be nice if OP gave us the test input"
templates = Path(filename).absolute().parents[2].joinpath('templates')
```

`templates` is still a `Path` object. Some API's accept `Path` but you can also do `templates = str(templates)` to get the path string.

Answer (score 1):

Since `os.path.dirname` gets the directory name for a specified file (in your case `__file__`, you can see what this means int [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do#:%7E:text=When%20a%20module%20is%20loaded,the%20file%20is%20located%20in.)) you will get the parent directory of that file.

Now `os.path.abspath` gets the absolute path of the current working directory with the file name.

And last `os.path.join` works by joining two paths. For example, if you have are located in `/opt/python/current/app/src/myproject/` and you want to join the `templates` folder to that path you do os.path.join(`/opt/python/current/app/src/myproject/`,`templates`)

so to get what you need you to do to get what you need

```python
'DIRS' : [os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))),
'templates')
],
```

`os.path.abspath` gets the absolute normalized path of `__file__` then it gets the parent directory with first `os.path.dirname` (innermost) and the second gets that resultant path parent directory and so on.

If by using two `os.path.dirname` you get `/opt/python/current/app/src/myproject/templates` that means you need one more `os.path.dirname` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(**file**))), "templates"))