# How to Give Module Access to Non-Python File

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following directory structure:

```
lib/
  main.py
  module1/
    __init__.py
    class1.py
    foo.txt
```

My `class1.py` file defines a class that has a function that reads the text file. My `main.py` creates an object from the class defined in `class1.py` and attempts to use the function to read the text file in the `module1` folder. However, when I run the main.py file, it says that it can't find the `foo.txt` file. How do I give `main.py` access to `foo.txt` through `class1.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do) attribute of the module. Since you know where `foo.txt` is located with respect to `class1.py`, you can simply use

```
# inside class1.py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'foo.txt'
```

This will work always, no matter where you call the script, or what script is the entry point.

#### Reasoning

- Absolute paths should only be used in quick "one time use scripts".
- Running a script should not (in most cases) rely on the fact in which folder the script is ran.
- Another way would be to have the static resources in a separate folder, and then read the file using relative paths, like above (Using pathlib is very handy).

#### Drawbacks

- You'll need to find a workaround if you plan to build and executable with pyinstaller or alike, since the `__file__` attribute is not anymore pointing to a `.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `class1.py` from `main.py`, your working directory is `lib/` (or wherever you called `main.py` from) and **not** `module1`.

This means that if you want to access `foo.txt` you need to **specify the path from the working directory**, not from where the `class1.py` is located.

---

#### Example:

Assuming that you run `main.py` from directory `lib/`:

```py
# class1.py

class Foo():

    def read1(self):
        try:
            f = open('foo.txt')
            print("Successfully opened 'foo.txt'.")
            print(f.read())
        except OSError:
            print("Error when trying to read 'foo.txt'.")

    def read2(self):
        try:
            f = open('module1/foo.txt')
            print("Successfully opened 'module1/foo.txt'.")
            print(f.read())
        except OSError:
            print("Error when trying to read 'module1/foo.txt'.")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    foo = Foo()
    foo.read1()
    foo.read2()
```

```py
# __init__.py

from module1.class1 import Foo
```

```py
# main.py

from module1 import Foo

foo = Foo()
foo.read1()
foo.read2()
```

- If you are inside `module1` and run `class1.py`:

```
Successfully opened 'foo.txt'.
...file contents...

Error when trying to read 'module1/foo.txt'.
```

As you can see `read1` worked and not `read2`.

- If you are in `lib/` and call `main.py`, you'll get:

```
Error when trying to read 'foo.txt'.
Successfully opened 'module1/foo.txt'.
...file contents...
```

This time `read2()` worked and not `read1()`.

Notes:

- if you call `class1.py` directly from `lib/module1` then `read_file_1()` will work instead of `read_file_2()`.
- you can alleviate this issue completely by using **absolute paths***

Comment: But they don't open it explicitly in `main.py`. It is opened through a function in `class1.py`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes but this is imported and *called* from `main.py` .

Comment: Yes but my point is that the function is in `class1.py` (inside a class) which means that the opening of the file is of the form `open('foo.txt')`. Then, as you indicated correctly, when running `main.py` the working directory is `lib` so the above `open` wouldn't work

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, Tomerikoo is correct

Comment: @AlexPeniz it does work... I added an example so you can run it by yourself.

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, but if you change the path ti will work...

Comment: Calling a different function according to the main module seems an inconvenient workaround... The way to go here is according to the link I provided above with `resources`. Or,  if this is not really a package, then just use an absolute path...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't think it's a good practice for a script to be able to be called from two possible locations. `class1.py` should be **only** called through the `main.py` module and I think the OP never stated that he wanted otherwise. I'm advocating for changing `'foo.txt'` with `'module1/foo.txt'`. The two functions were just to show how it works... Also absolute imports aren't always possible (e.g. when writing a module).

Comment: I simplified my problem to just a text file. It's actually a Lark grammar file that uses lark.open, so it may not work the same way. For some reason using this method didn't yield the correct result, but thank you for your answer!