# __file__ on some modules return None

Tags: python, file, import, module, nonetype

I run the _*file*_ function over a many modules using a for loop and for some modules I get None. I saw that this can be happened to file that doesn't have _*init*_ file but I can't add a _*init*_ file to those who have't because it's a lot of files.

Is there any other option to get the same data instead using _*file*_ so I won't get a None?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271617/4498470

The modules that have set `__file__ = None` are probably modules written in C. They are statically linked. Or perhaps the import system has loaded in the module from a database and so there is no 'file' to point to.

I'd say if there's no `__file__` attribute set, unless it's a bug, it probably because that attribute is meaningless for a particular module.

Python's import system is pretty complicated. You can read some about the attributes like `__file__` here https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/import.html?highlight=__file__#import-related-module-attributes.

So, the answer to "Is there any other option to get the same data instead using *file* so I won't get a None" is probably No. (At least for C Python).