# Running a python file within a different directory

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, directory, subprocess

How could I run the entirety of `test.py` from `main.py`. Both `main.py` and `test.py` is allocated within the application folder. The `test.py` file is within the app folder. How would I be able to achieve this, the code I have below does not work?

Directories:

```
application folder
├── appFolder
│   └──test.py
└── main.py
```

Main.py:

```
from .appFolder import test
from subprocess import call
call(["Python3","test.py"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything, just reference the folder name in `main.py`. To make it more robust, you should probably use a relative file otherwise you might get some odd results depending on where `main.py` is called from.

```
import os.path
from subprocess import call

d = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # application folder
call(["python3", f"{d}/appFolder/test.py"])
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/1904146