# How to run an .exe from the same folder as my Python program

Tags: python

The title may not be the best description of what I'm trying to do. I made a few simple lines of code to run a .exe, in this case the adobe reader installer.

```
import os
os.system('"D:/Python Project/Work Project/Installers/readerdc_en_xa_crd_install.exe"')
```

currently the code and .exe are in the same folder but if I were to move the entire folder to another machine obviously the file path for the .exe would no longer be the same. How do I go about running a .exe that is in the same folder as the code without relying on the entire file path of the machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
os.system( f'"{mypath}/readerdc_en_xa_cer_install.exe"' )
```

Comment: ok im being dumb what should be in the parenthesis after dirname? should it be the name of the .exe or?

Comment: [It's literally `__FILE__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9271464/9997212).

Comment: that returns an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Project/Work Project/GUITest/InstallTest.py", line 2, in <module>
    mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__FILE__))
NameError: name '__FILE__' is not defined

Comment: Try `__file__` rather than `__FILE__`.

Comment: that worked but now i get an error
"'D:\Python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @BenHille Did you remember the `"` inside the `'`?