# When I am trying to run the following code I have got this error "NameError: name '__file__' is not defined"

Tags: python

```
    path_wd = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
            '..',
            'temp',
            str(time.time())
        )
    )
    os.makedirs(path_wd)

    # GET DATASET #
    
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    # Normalize input so we can train ANN with it.
    `enter code here`# Will be converted back to integers for SNN layer.
    x_train = x_train / 255
    x_test = x_test / 255

    axis = 1 if keras.backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis)
    x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis)..
```

Comment: Are you running this code in a Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running the code in interactive mode (typing in a command line interface).

This is meant to work when the code is in a .py file. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/4653485.)

I suppose you copy-pasted this from a tutorial. Replace the whole thing with the path you want to use as working directory.

```
    path_wd = "/home/ramapati/path_to_temp_dir/"
    os.makedirs(path_wd)

    ...
```