# When import a python file into another (in a subdirectory) it stops finding the csv in the same directory

Tags: python, path, operating-system, sys

I'm trying to import the cleaning file in the managers file like this:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("cleaning.py")))
from cleaning import df_invoices_full
```

The main folder contains the files cleaning, transaction listing and a sub folder called "apps" with the managers file:

[image]

Also note that the cleaning file reads the transaction listing.csv file.

The issue I'm getting when running is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Transaction Listing.csv'
```

And "Transaction Listings.csv" is correctly loaded by cleaning but no when cleaning is imported into maganagers.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post a [mre] of the relevant code in `cleaning.py`.

Comment: cleaning.py works well on its own FYI

Comment: `df_invoices_full = pd.read_csv("Transaction Listing.csv", encoding='latin-1')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#-- cleaning.py --#

import os
import pandas as pd

csv_filename = "Transaction Listings.csv"
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path_to_csv = os.path.join(folder, csv_filename)

df_invoices_full = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, encoding="latin-1")
```

Use this code in `cleaning.py` instead of your current code.

What is happening is that when `cleaning.py` is imported into `apps/managers.py`, it runs in the `apps` folder, not the base folder where the CSV files are located. By giving the absolute path, `pd.read_csv()` will look in the correct place for the file - the directory that `cleaning.py` actually resides in. See [what does the __file__ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do).

Comment: Yeah that was indeed the issue, good to know how it works, thanks a lot Matt, you rock!