# Selenium firefox profile download directory preference not getting implemented

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

I have the following code

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/zip")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

But when the zip file gets downloaded it still gets downloaded to my temp dir.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two minor modifications as follows:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

with:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

followed by the line:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
```

Effectively, your code block will be:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/zip")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

---

### References

You can find a detailed discussion on *`os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`* in [what does the **file** variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Comment: It's still downloading into the temp dir, I made a way around this by just moving the file out of temp but that's not a solid work around as the file it is downloading could change names