# Python script creates folders, how to reference path- absolute vs relative?

Tags: python, file

I have a parent folder named A, which contains my Python script. The script creates a sub folder, also within A.

I'm unsure how I should reference the path when creating the new sub folder because:

1. I can't use absolute path because each user will have their username as part of the path to the Git repo.
2. I'm worried about using relative path because I don't know from which folder users will execute the script.

How is this typically handled?

Comment: Tell your users to run the script from a specific directory so they don't do it wrong. Or write some code that navigates backwards until it finds your directory (not sure if that would meet your requirements though)

Comment: You can construct an absolute path given a user name. Can you provide more details about how `A` and the user's name will be used?

Answer (score 1):

use [`__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do) to get the path to the python script you are in, regardless of where the script is run from.

```
from pathlib import Path
script_path_dir = Path(__file__).parent
sub_folder = script_path_dir / 'your_subfolder'
```