# Wrong path when calling file through function in diffrent folder

Tags: python

i'm trying to open a file by calling a function in a diffrent folder.

---Folder1
------reader.py
------data.txt
---Folder2
------main.py

(didn't know how to visualize it better)

In reader i try to set the path with
`os.path.abspath("./data.txt")`
which works only as long as i run the code within Folder1.
When i try to open "data.txt" by calling the function through "main.py" the path it tries to take is ".../Folder2/data.txt".

Now I know that i can just set the path in "main.py" and add it as a parameter, but since I am going to call the "reader.py" from more than one source, this, while possible, isn't optimal.
I hope some of you might have a solution,
Ignitz

Comment: See this question for getting paths relative to file where your code resides: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does the \_\_file\_\_ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)