# How to get the current script name that is called

Tags: python

I have a Python script named Build_all.py and in this Build_all.py I called several other scripts named First_build.py, Second_build.py, etc to run. Inside each First/Second_build.py I want to have a variable to automatically save the script name that is called. How should I do it?

In other words, how to get the name of the python script that is called - not the python file which is currently executing.

I search online and find that `sys.argv[0]` and `inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())` and `__file__`. But all of these three methods give me the current executing script name (Build_all.py) not what I want (First_build.py)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does the \_\_file\_\_ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Comment: `__file__` shouldn't give `Build_all.py` from inside `First_build.py`. How are you using it? Make a [mre]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: How are you calling the other scripts? As subproceses or with `import`?

Comment: if you call `__name__` from within First_build.py and import First_build into Build_all, you should get First_build

Comment: @Barmar I am using exec(open("..xxx.py").read())

Comment: That won't set `__file__` to `xxx.py`, if that's what you want. The string that you're executing has no recollection of the file it was read from.