# How to create a Python application that does not have any absolute paths?

Tags: python, file

Okay so if I am going to make a Python application that will be distributed to others I need all the file paths to not be absolute, but relative to the root directory (I believe).

Let's say the file system looks something like this:

```
root
 |
 | - app.py
 | - data
 |    |
 |    | - file1.txt
 |    | - file2.txt
 |
 | - src
      |
      | - python_file.py
```

Of course the file system would be more complex than this. However, let's say I need the python_file.py to grab the file1.txt. How would you do this for an application that cannot use any absolute paths. I assume it is with the os module, I have seen some examples, but many of them are different, and some do not work.

I would love to know how to do this so that all the files can interact together correctly for any system ('dynamically' so to speak).

Comment: I believe there was something like `import ..data.file1` but I don't quite remember

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using a tag. The `distribution` tag doesn't mean what you think.

Comment: " I need all the file paths to not be absolute, but relative to the root directory (I believe)." I guess they just need to be all relative to *some* path in your project, not necessarily the root directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll simplify your layout a bit and make it a single package (which could live in an `src` layout; you generally don't want an `app.py` outside an `src` layout):

- `justins_app/`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `__main__.py` (this is run when you invoke `python -m justins_app`)
  - `consts.py`
  - `data/`

    - `file1.txt`
    - `file2.txt`

Now, `consts.py` could simply have

```
import pathlib

data_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "data"
```

to determine `data/` from the [`__file__` magic global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/51685) and you could then do e.g.

```
from justins_app.consts import data_path

file1_path = data_path / "file1.txt"
print(file1_path.read_text())
```

in another module.

Then, when you distribute this, you'd tell your packaging system to include the data directory in the package too (see e.g. [here](https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/#file-selection) for Hatch's instructions for that).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I want looking for!