# How do I make pygame load an image from the same directory, without typing in what that directory is?

Tags: python, pygame, operating-system

When I am trying to load an image, it always checks the root directory for it, "C:\Users*name*"
I am trying to get an image to load from the same folder as the program is in, and I don't know what I am doing differently from all of the other Stack Overflow problems I've looked at. It does work to load an image if I put it into the root directory, though.
`back = pygame.image.load('BackRoom.jpg').convert()`

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this, and sorry if this is just a really easy thing that I didn't know how to do. Thank you.

I tried putting the picture into the same folder as the program, but that doesn't work.

Comment: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`. See [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#file__) and [what does the __file__ variable mean/do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do)

Comment: Thank you for helping I was able to get it to work. The file variable was just so that I could load the file. Thank you for helping, and sorry if this was a duplicate question.