# Python Import is failing with error message ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

I'm working with Python and have this directory structure:

```
/new/uiautomation/testscripts/dropdown_test.py
/new/uiautomation/apis/runner.py
/new/apis/restapi.py

from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
```

In my dropdown_test.py file, located within testscripts, I want to import restapi.py and runner.py, both located in different directories. The apis directory is not directly above testscripts, so how can I import these modules without hardcoding the project directory name (new)? Here's what I've tried:

```
from apis.runner import Runner
from ..apis.restapi import Login
```

However, this isn't working as expected. Is there a way to provide relative import statements without specifying the project directory name?"

Only problem is that i am not able to resolve or import apis/restapi.py inside my testscripts/dropdown_test.py

Comment: from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )

Comment: @Ammad - OP is correct, `__file__` is the appropriate variable, as this dunder contains the [path to the file being executed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271479/6340496).

Comment: 1) Use `sys.path.insert(0, ...)`. Note the use of **insert**, as you want this to be the *first* path encountered, not the last. 2) Add one more `os.path.dirname`, as this will bring your `sys.path` to `/new`. Then, you can use `from uiautomation.apis.runner import Runner ` and `from apis.restapi import Login`.  Alternatively, have *two* `insert` calls which will place `/new` and `/new/uiautomation` into `sys.path`, and simplify the first `import` to: `from apis.runner import Runner`.  However, it's not ideal having *two* directories named `apis`.

Comment: from uiautomation.apis.runner import Runner fix the issue. Can you move  your comment to  answer section.  THanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I don't post answers to [(near)-duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time). However, [at the request of OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78196062/python-import-is-failing-with-error-message-importerror-attempted-relative-impo/78196552#comment137857997_78196062), here's an answer based on the comment.

There are a couple ways to fix this. For simplicity I'll offer one - as listed in my comment.

1. Use `sys.path.insert(0, ...)`

Note the use of `.insert`, as you want this to be the *first* path encountered, not the last.

2. Add one more `os.path.dirname`, as this will bring your `sys.path` to `/new`.

Then, you can use:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(
                   os.path.dirname(
                   os.path.dirname(
                   os.path.realpath(__file__)))))

from uiautomation.apis.runner import Runner  
from apis.restapi import Login
```

---

Alternatively, have *two* `.insert` calls which will place `/new` and `/new/uiautomation` into `sys.path`, and simplify the imports to:

```
from apis.runner import Runner  
from apis.restapi import Login
```

However, this is confusing and not ideal having two directories named `apis`.

Comment: The only reason this fix seems "specific" or the duplicate seems only "near" is because [Python import canonicals on Stack Overflow are a complete mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423857/rfc-doing-something-about-python-import-canonicals-before-i-lose-my-mind).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Fair point. However, updated to show the answer was posted [at OPs request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78196062/python-import-is-failing-with-error-message-importerror-attempted-relative-impo/78196552#comment137857997_78196062).  Please kindly retract the unnecessary downvote.  Don't make your bug-bear turn into an act of unkindness or spite.  Let's be mature here.

Comment: from uiautomation.apis.runner import Runner  This line did the trick.  @s3dev